# Unimplemented handling of missing static target, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing my Flutter code but I keep getting the error of Unimplemented handling of missing the static target. there is no other error give so I don't know why I'm getting this and there is no way for me to debug it. 
The error I'm getting is:

```
══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CompileTimeError was thrown building Wrapper(dirty, dependencies: [InheritedProvider<User>], state: _Wrapper#576d6):
Unimplemented handling of missing static target

The relevant error-causing widget was
    Wrapper 
lib\main.dart:28
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4334
#1      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4223
#2      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
#3      StatefulElement.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4413
#4      Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2977
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 5 of 544 libraries in 350ms.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Unimplemented handling of missing static target
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Wrapper
```

My code is :

```
import 'package:sociagrowapp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:sociagrowapp/HomePages/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sociagrowapp/Authenticate/authenticate.dart';
//import 'package:package_info/package_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:sociagrowapp/services/firestore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _Wrapper();
}

class _Wrapper extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future getversionnumber() async {

      var data = http.get('https://sociagrow.com/version.html');
      print(data);
      return data;
    }

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getversionnumber(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
            print(user);
            var version = snapshot.data;
            // return either the Home or Authenticate widget
            if (version == false) {
              return Text('Oh no You need to update');
            } else {
              if (user == null) {
                print('Should Changed 3');
                return Scaffold(body: Authenticate());
              } else {
                return PageData();
              }
            }
          } else {
            return SpinKitThreeBounce(
              color: Colors.blue,
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

The strange part is that when I debug it in visual studio code it runs but when I resave and hot reload it I get this error. The problem is not in the http.get() because I got the error with other future functions and firestore as well. really strange though I haven't encountered this type of error and I can't find anything about this error in the internet that could be helpful.

Comment: Can you try adding type `_Wrapper ` to `createState()`

Comment: The error still occurs after a hot load. I added the type

Comment: Try by restarting. Hot reload not works for those changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be hot-reload cache lead to this problem, I just encounter the same problem and I fixed it by stop project then restart it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by stopping the debugging or terminate the app.
[image]

Then, try to restart or debug the app.
[image]